# sum of one column with condition using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have data table with some columns like this:

e.g :

```
  WorkHour     Salary    Name
     60          100      A
     70          120      B
     65          105      C
```

Sum of WorkHour:   **195**

Sum of Salary  :   **225**

I want sum of columns "WorkHour" and "Salary" but with condition:
If Name==A add WorkHour to sum but not add it's Salary.

Here is my code:

```
var resultSum = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<string>("UserId") into grp
                select new
                {
                    Salary = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Salary")),
                    WorkHour = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("WorkHour"))
                };

foreach (var rn in resultSum)
{
    decimal dSalary = rn.Salary;
    decimal WorkHour = rn.WorkHour;
}
```

Comment: LINQ 2 SQL, LINQ 2 Objects, entity framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the records and then when calculating the `Salary` add a `Where` before the `Sum`:

```
var result = (from item in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group item by item.Field<string>("UserId") into g
              select
              {
                  Salary = g.Where(i => i.Field<string>("Name") != "A")
                            .Sum(i => i.Field<decimal>("Salary")),
                  WorkHour = g.Sum(i => i.Field<decimal>("WorkHour"))
              }).ToList();
```